# triangular float

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is there a way to make a triangular float so that a page looks something like the following:

```
            This is a sampe
        Page that has a 
    Triangle left float
That looks kind of cool.
```

Theoretically the content inside is naturally going to be variable, so I'd prefer to do it in an 'automatic' way so that when the actual words/descriptions come in it doesn't affect where I have to place content. You have free form to use whatever HTML/CSS/JS combo, but the simpler the better =)

If it helps, Originally I tried putting divs of varying lengths float left with a clear left, but naturally when I placed the text, it came after everything and floating it right didn't work.

Comment: Do you want all the text to be in a single tag? So just `<p>Some text</p>` and then the float is completely automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: put some floating blocks next to each other, each one line higher than the next. That will create a (transparent) triangular block.

```
body {line-height:1.2em}
.blk1 {float:left; width:10px; height:6.0em}
.blk2 {float:left; width:10px; height:4.8em}
.blk3 {float:left; width:10px; height:3.6em}
.blk4 {float:left; width:10px; height:2.4em}
.blk5 {float:left; width:10px; height:1.2em}
```

And the HTML will be

```
<div class="blk1"></div>
<div class="blk2"></div>
<div class="blk3"></div>
<div class="blk4"></div>
<div class="blk5"></div>
<div>Your text here.</div>
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsHKb/). Can you work with that?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of layout will get much easier once the [CSS exclusions and shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/) module has been implemented in browsers (looks like Chrome canary builds exhibit some initial support.)